# How do I select records where a value has not been exceeded

Tags: sql, db2

I wish to extract from a database a list of job Ids where the status for each job has not exceeded a given criteria.

For this example table I want to display all the jobid that have not exceeded status 200 and display only the latest status.

Job-Progress table

```
Jobid Status Date      Time
1234  100    20131001  080000
1234  200    20131001  100000
1234  300    20131001  140000
9876  100    20131014  110000
5555  100    20131015  100000
5555  200    20131016  080000
```

The result i am looking for is

```
Jobid Status Date      Time
9876  100    20131014  110000
5555  200    20131016  080000
```

Database is on AS400

Comment: Please state your RDBMS

Comment: Is the status field numeric or character?

Comment: @Yosi saying the system is "AS/400" (current name is IBM i  on Power Systems) tells us DB2 which is integrally woven into the IBM i operating system (formerly "OS/400", "i5/OS")

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use of window/analytic functions.

You can use `row_number()` to get the most recent status.  You can use `sum() over` to count the number of times that status exceeds 200.

```
select jobid, Status, Date, Time
from (select jp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by jobid order by date desc, time desc) as seqnum,
             sum(case when status >= 200 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by jobid) as status_200
      from JobProgress jp
     ) jp
where status_200 = 0 and seqnum = 1;
```

The `where` clause then filters to the rows you are looking for.

Comment: If the status can decrease again, then the check for the status <= 200 needs to be moved to the where clause of the outer select.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
inner join 
(
  select Jobid, max(date*1000000+time) as maxdt
  from your_table
  group by jobid
  having sum(case when status > 200 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
) t2 on t1.jobid = t2.jobid 
     and t1.date*100000+t1.time = maxdt
```

Comment: If the status can decrease again, then the check for the status <= 200 needs to be moved to the where clause of the outer select.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
            Jobid,
            status,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Jobid ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
      FROM
            Job-Progress
      WHERE Status < 200) A
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Close, but this is for DB2 for i, not SQL Server.

Comment: Adapted syntax for you. But it will still return a row for jobid 1234, eh?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest approach I can think of:

```
SELECT t.* FROM t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT jobid, max(date) date FROM t
  GROUP BY jobid
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status > 200 THEN 1 END) = 0
) s
ON t.jobid = s.jobid AND t.date = s.date
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8401/1).

Answer (score 0):

A common table expression will allow you to employ the ROW_NUMBER() function to mark the latest row of each job as 1. Then all you need to do is pick that row whenever its status is acceptable.

```
With x as
(SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Jobid ORDER BY Date, time DESC) AS pick
      FROM JobProgress
)
SELECT jobid, status, date, time
  FROM x
  WHERE Status <= 200
    And pick = 1
```

Comment: This method is efficient if the status values cannot decrease.